# How can I catch ORA-28011or ORA-28002 in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, passwords, handle

I must handle the ORA-28011 and ORA-28002 in my app. But these ORA warnings suppressed by JDBC (I think)
How can I catch these in Java?
Is there something JDBC property?

I don't prefer the direct query the status from `dba_users` table.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are **not** suppressed by JDBC. You can use [`Connection#getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getWarnings%28%29) (`Connection`-related warnings) to retrieve the first warning that was reported by your database, and then, use [`SQLWarning#getErrorCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29) to obtain the vendor-specific warning code that was thrown, which for an Oracle JDBC driver, will give you the `ORA` number:

```
Connection connection;
// ...
SQLWarning warn = connection.getWarnings();
int errorCode = warn.getErrorCode();
if (errorCode == 28011) {
  // ORA-28011
} else if (errorCode == 28002) {
  // ORA-28002
}
```

If you want to fetch more warnings, use [`SQLWarning#getNextWarning()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLWarning.html#getNextWarning%28%29).

#### References:

- [Handling SQL Exceptions -- Retrieving Warnings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html#retrieving_warnings)